# Why ConverterParameter is not bindable in wpf and Silverlight?

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight

I am learning wpf for a couple of weeks and I am surprised that WPF / Silverlight has the powerful binding feature.

I am also surprised that some properties do not support binding e.g converterparameter. I found that this one is a primitive datatype so we can't bind it with other sources.

I would like to find out why these kind of properties are not bindable?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not bindable because [IValueConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)s are not part of the logical tree.
Therefore, they don't inherit the DataContext that makes DataBinding possible.

You can find [several](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mikehillberg/archive/2008/05/21/model-see_2c00_-model-do.aspx) [tricks](http://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2008/06/26/datacontextspy/) on how to make such an object inherit the DataContext, but I would recommand against it: it's hackish, and in the end it will harm the readability of your code (nobody expects bound stuff in an IValueConverter).

Comment: thanks man. but what about the others like stringformat etc. is it the same case.

Comment: stringformat on a binding is not bindable because Binding is not part of the logical tree itself.